# What is the biggest drawbacks on creating classes of everything? Instead of String name = person.getName() it would be Name name = person.getName();

Tags: java, oop, class, object

What is the biggest drawbacks if I were to create type of everything, instead of using Strings and primitive types?

Normally it would look like:

```
String name = person.getName();
int age = person.getAge();
```

But now "everything" is objectified, you seldom handle Strings (unless you need specific String manipulation).

```
Name name = person.getName();
Age age = person.getAge();
```

Where `Name` and `Age` would be (in this example) simple container classes:

```
public class Name {

    private final String name;

    public Name(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Overide
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

However, in the future, they can have more more methods and validations, etc.

But the bottom line is that you basically create types for everything.

I know this makes the code more type safe, but what are the biggest drawbacks for this kind of code convention?

Comment: I think String and primitives generalize the want to implement a functionality. Making classes of everything would add complexity coz it would depend on the perspective of the person using or implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

The code gets more verbose and not all libraries deal equally well with this pattern.

I try to strike a balance in Java code, I use quite a lot of primitives and strings, but some data types, such as monetary amounts and social security numbers get their own dedicated classes. An SSN has its internal validation rules. Monetary calculations benefit from explicit control over rounding and guards against adding amounts in different currency.

In languages less verbose than Java, I tend to use more of these dedicated classes than I do in Java.

Comment: +1 for monetary calculations. I've seen an application storing prices as long values that had to be divided by 100.0 and formatted all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The only real drawback to this is that the more code you write, the more code you have to maintain and test. Theoretically this is a great idea. It's the practical side that causes the issues.

Answer (score 0):

- It's unnecessarily verbose
- You may lose immutability (in this case `Name` is immutable, but it's more error prone)

If you need more fields later you can easily add them. Keep your code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Class Explosion will make your code difficult to follow and understand.**

When someone sees `String name`, they know immediately what that object is.  All java developers know about the `String` class.  When someone sees `Name name`, they have no idea what the `Name` class is.  What does it do?  What functionality does it add?

If this class only just extends `Name` and does nothing else, then it's pointless and a waste of time for a developer coming in to work on the code.  If this class does do something else, then of course you need to make the class to get the functionality.

Bottom line: if you're adding extra functionality, create your own class.  If you just need the functionality in `String`, then just use `String`.  You can always create `Name` and refactor later if you need additional functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't ever recommend changing the type of a property. That tends to sneak in all kinds of small bugs (reflection, casting, ...) - been there, fixed that. It there's a valid chance of a future refactoring, it's a good starting point to already have a dedicated class. And regarding your first argument: how often do you bring new developers to a project and how much time does it take to grasp the functionality of such a simple class? I'd say it's one short glance per new developer and that's it. As some IDE's show Javadoc as tooltips, it might not even be necessary to open the class.

Comment: Unless this was done throughout the project, in which case it is countless short glances per new developer.  You have to design assuming new developers are going to come into the project.  Business needs require people to change focus.  Things happen.  If there's a valid chance at a future refactoring, then you can start building out the properties of the class now and it's not merely a wrapper.  Additionally, tools like Eclipse make this type of refactoring easy without sneaking in all kinds of small bugs.  Sometimes you have to change the type of a property.  It's okay.

Comment: It's also better than the alternative.  A codebase with a bunch of placeholders for future code is messy.  When requirements change before the future gets here, the placeholders become roadblocks.  It's much better to simply code for now and make modifications in the future when functionality is clear.

Comment: I've learnt this one the hard way. Refactoring isn't all that trivial, Eclipse can't do anything for you (reflections, casting, things like HQL queries, ...). So I think that the answer to this question depends heavily on many small factors. I'll continue to trust my gut feeling here but I certainly think that you've mentioned some valid points. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this, for the simple reason if you are integrating with other systems (e.g. web services in different parts of the organisation or third-party vendors, you'll end up having to deal with Strings and int's anyway and you'll have to make your code even more complex by having to wrap names in `Name` objects when you get them from other systems and unwrapping them when you want to post them to other systems.

I'd say Keep it Simple, and validation could easily be introduced using bean validation [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303).

Also, what happens if you needed different validation rules for `Name`s on different objects, e.g. an organisation name is different from a person name, before you know it you'll have a whole class hierarchy to deal with which if you want to change a name would be a refactoring nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

There have been times when I regretted not creating classes for object that were represented by simple strings (venue and tour of a concert being examples). I did this to follow the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) for what was expected to be a very simple application

I can't remember that I ever regretted creating a class in such cases. There's certainly some more maintenance and boiler plate involved. But still, from a gut feeling, if you feel it could pay off in the future (refactoring, maybe even performance) I'd say go for it. It's a small investment that can save you from major headaches. But try not to overdo it.